# How to access HP ALM using REST and local javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, alm

I just want to access **ALM** via local written javascript js in the browser (IE11, Firefox) via the `REST` API but I can not login. Here is my code for requesting the `LWSSO` cookie via jquery:

```
var auth = btoa(USER+":"+PASSWORD);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: https://alm.xxx.net/qcbin/authentication-point/j_spring_security_check,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + auth
    },
    success : function(data) { },
});
```

The response header contains:

> https://alm.xxx.net/qcbin/authentication-point/login.jsp;jsessionid=1gfsdk4pn525f1ur55e2x2zzte?login_error

With `OTA/directX` object everything works fine but I want to use the `REST` API via javascript. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -1):

First of all; which version of ALM are you using? Second, I think you are using the wrong URL for the authentication point. According to the documentation (for ALM 12.01) it should be https://alm.xxx.net/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate.

Also, the HTTP method you use should be GET, **not** POST.

I noticed that you are using https in the URL, so I assume your instance of ALM is set up with that?

Comment: Im using ALM 11.50.555. The authentication is now possible via https://alm.xxx.net/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate and the LWSSO cookie is returned from the alm server if I submit my credentials via XML.

But I have a new problem: Ajax requests with jquery to ALM Server result in cross origin requests which are blocked from the browser. CORS is not supported by ALM. Do you guys have any solution for that?

Comment: I found a post where using [Chrome extensions that intercepts and rewrites CORS headers is suggested: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/Custom-WebApp-using-ALM-Rest/td-p/6054667#.VcjDNZOqqko. Alternatively, you could use HP UFT/Service Test to perform calls the REST API. What is the use case for the application you are creating?