# How to access hp alm with rest api javascript: automatic login

Tags: javascript, rest, alm

I just want to access ALM via local written javascript in the browser (IE11, Firefox, Chrome) via the REST API but I can not login. 
I tried to use the code shown in [How to access HP ALM using REST and local javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670129/how-to-access-hp-alm-using-rest-and-local-javascript) , but there is always the same Error: OPTIONS https://alm.....net/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate 401 (An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext)

Maybe the problem is, that I don't know how to

> submit my credentials via XML

as mentioned in the link. Could you please help me?

Me Code is:

```
function signinTest() {var auth = btoa(name + ":" + password);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'https://alm.....net/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + auth
            }, 
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("succes " + data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("error ");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have mixed

> /authentication-point/**alm-authenticate**

and

> /authentication-point/**authenticate**

REST resources.

If you want to log in using credentials in XML you need to use **alm-authenticate** resource (see [alm-authenticate doc](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/Content/REST/alm-authenticate.html)).

For **authenticate** you need to send user information in headers and use GET method (see [Authenticate doc](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/api_refs/Performance_Center_REST_API/Content/authenticate.htm)).

---

Use *data* and *contentType* to send XML via Ajax in the POST.
For example:

```
function signinTest() {var auth = btoa(name + ":" + password);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://alm.....net/qcbin/authentication-point/alm-authenticate',
        data: "<alm-authentication><user>USERNAME</user><password>PASSWORD</password></alm-authentication>",
        type: "POST",       
        contentType: "text/xml",
        ...
```